# What is an idiom similar to Karma?

Tags: idiom-requests

What is an idiom similar to Karma?  Something like "What goes around comes around"

Comment: Something similar is "sow the wind and reap the whirlwind": see https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/sow_the_wind,_reap_the_whirlwind also, "got his [just deserts](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=just+deserts&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=GHmCWt3NM4SjX9e5gaAO)" as in "got what he deserved" (whether good or bad outcome.)

Comment: "chickens come home to roost" is one... but generally heard for things that aren't so good ... odd because I'd hope my chicken would come home if I had a chicken

Comment: Also "[pay it forward](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=pay+it+forward+idiom&client=firefox-b&dcr=0&hl=en&sa=X&as_q=&nfpr=&spell=1&ved=0ahUKEwjPwOyslqLZAhXINY8KHXfYALQQvwUICg)" and ["one good turn deserves another"](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=one+good+turn+deserves+another&client=firefox-b&dcr=0&hl=en&oq=one+good+turn+deserves+another&gs_l=mobile-heirloom-serp.12...0.0.1.2462.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..34.mobile-heirloom-serp..0.3.666.1UBoyhPN4Co).

Comment: What's wrong with "what goes around, comes around"? You need to be more specific about what you're looking for (right now your question is in danger of being closed as it isn't clear what you want, or what the criteria for judging answers should be).

Answer (score 2):

Our understanding of 'Karma' is 'An action always have a reaction'.

So one of the idioms can be "As you sow, so shall you reap"

Answer (score 0):

The answer by  [English Hupp Technologies](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/281171/english-hupp-technologies) pretty much explains the meaning.
I would also like to add what most people also say and use :

> You get what you give.

But it's not to be confused with "You get what you pay for".

more information [here](https://www.definitions.net/definition/you%20only%20get%20what%20you%20give) and for [You get what you pay for](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/you+get+what+you+pay+for) . Hope this clarifies.